# Snowflake JDBC drivers - use with Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I am having trouble connecting Oracle Data Modeler to a Snowflake database using a JDBC driver.

I am hoping someone can share some trouble shooting tips with me to help solve my problem.

The error I am getting when I try to test the connection is

"Status : Failure -Test failed: Driver class not found.

Verify the Driver location"

I have downloaded the jar file from the nominated spot in the Snowflake documentation.

I am able to add the jar file to Tools->Preferences->Data Model->Third Party JDBC Drivers.

When I  add the data source using File->Import->Data Dictionary using

url - jdbc:snowflake://.ap-southeast-2.snowflakecomputing.com
driver class - net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
I get the error when I try to Test.

I suppose the hint if 'Verify the Driver location' but didn't I specify that when I set up my preferences.

Is there a trick with path or another variable that helps with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the tag `oracle` only for the database, not for the many, many other products of the company Oracle. You could user oracle-sqldeveloper, of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to use net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver as the driver class in your JDBC application. Also, your connection string should have the following syntax: jdbc:snowflake://account_name.snowflakecomputing.com

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running a sample program shared in documentation to validate the JDB driver installation:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-using.html#java-sample-program

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion.  I was able to trouble shoot my issues using this tool.  The first issue was I needed to make sure the java\jdk folder (not the jre folder) was in my path; and the second issue (I am embarassed to admit it but it may help someone else) I had downloaded the wrong file from from the maven repository.  I had downloaded the latest version *.javadoc.jar file because it was at the top of the list...it should have been the *.jar file...oops.  Thanks again.